# Why string type is not being accepted if it was expected?

Tags: oop, ocaml

I am trying to create and use a stack object (modified to have strings) from [here](https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html):

```
let s = object
    val mutable v = [""; ""]

    method pop =
      match v with
      | hd :: tl -> 
        v <- tl;
        Some hd
      | [] -> None

    method push hd = 
      v <- hd :: v
  end ;;

let () = 
    s#push "first";
    s#push "second";
    s#push "third";
    print_endline  s#pop;   (* error from this line *)
    print_endline  s#pop;
    print_endline  s#pop;
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ ocaml objects.ml 

File "./objects.ml", line 19, characters 15-20:
Error: This expression has type string option
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

I am not able to understand the error: If the expected type was string why expression of type string is not being accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not able to understand the error: If the expected type was string why expression of type string is not being accepted?

Because the expression `s#pop` doesn't have type `string`. Its type is `string option`, i.e., it is either `Some s` or `None`, where `s` has type `string`.

Look at the `pop` method implementation, which returns `Some s` if there are more elements waiting in the stack, or `None` if the stack is empty,

```
method pop =
  match v with
  | hd :: tl -> 
    v <- tl;
    Some hd  (* returns `Some hd` *)
  | [] -> None (* returns `None` *)
```

You can implement a helper function, that will print a value of type `string option`, e.g.,

```
 let print_some s = match s with
   | None -> print_endline "empty"
   | Some s -> print_endline s
```

Here is how it is used

```
let () =
  s#push "first";
  s#push "second";
  s#push "third";
  print_some  s#pop; 
  print_some  s#pop;
  print_some  s#pop;
```

Here are some alternative implementations of the `stack` object, that use other ways to communicate to the caller that the stack is empty, e.g., a sentinel value from the stack element domain (provided by a user), an exception, or the `result` type, parametrized with a stringly typed error.

```
let stack_with_sentinel empty = object
    val mutable v = []
    method pop = match v with
      | hd :: tl -> 
        v <- tl;
        hd
      | [] -> empty
  end

let stack_with_exception = object
    val mutable v = []
    method pop = match v with
      | hd :: tl -> 
        v <- tl;
        hd
      | [] -> raise Not_found
  end

let stack_with_result = object
    val mutable v = []
    method pop = match v with
      | hd :: tl -> 
        v <- tl;
        Ok hd
      | [] -> Error "empty stack"
  end
```

There are many other ways to define it, but using the `option` type is the most common.

Comment: Why `Some s` is used? Why not just `s`? Can `pop` method return top string in stack? Also, will `pop` method work if there is only one element in stack?

Comment: The `pop` method is inherently non-total, e.g., what it should return if the stack is empty? Several choices are available, you can return a value of the `option` type, raise an exception, or designate some sentinel value in the domain of the return value and return it, e.g., you can return an empty string `""` or a special string `"empty"`. Those are all different design choices, with different applicability in different scenarious. There is no the best choice, but using the option type is quite idiomatic in the modern OCaml.

Comment: It will be great if you can add code for pop fn that returns item on top of stack.